# Sum values in double nested List of Dictionaries in C#

Tags: c#, list, linq, dictionary, nested

I have (for certain reasons not to get into now...) a List of the following structure:

```
List1<Dictionary1<string, List2<Dictionary2<string, string>>>>
```

(I added the 1 and 2 naming for clarity).
I want to iterate over `List1` and sum up `Dictionary1`, so that all values of identical keys in `Dictionary2` will add up.

For example if each `Dictionary1` item contains a `Dictionary2`:
{ "Price", 23},
{ "Customers", 3}

then I want to iterate over all `List2` elements, and over all `List1` elements, and have a final dictionary of the total sum of all prices and customers as a single key for each category:
{ "Price", 15235},
{ "Customers", 236}

I hope that's clear.. In other words, I want to sum up this double-nested list in a way that I'm left with all unique keys across all nested dictionaries and have the values summed up.

I believe it can be done with LINQ, but I'm not sure how to do that..

Comment: Why is the the second type of "Dictionary2" string instead of double or some other numeric type?

Comment: What's the point of Dictionary1?  I don't see that key being used if I'm reading this right?

Comment: You need some better sample data, and your expected results, this is a little confusing

Comment: What is the depth of sub list, 2?

Comment: Just FYI, *"(I added the 1 and 2 naming for clarity)"* adding numbers to the end of type names does not clarify things, in fact quite the opposite. Instead, posting code that compiles is probably the best way to ensure clarity: `var data = new List<Dictionary<string, List<Dictionary<string, int>>>>();`. Please add a code snipped that actually populates some items in the list, and then state what the expected outcome should be.

Comment: *"if each Dictionary1 item contains a Dictionary2:"*. But `Dictionary1` does not contain a `Dictionary2`, it contains a `List<Dictionary2<>>`.

Comment: Any reason you aren't using a class with properties to represent your objects? i.e. `public class Item { public decimal Price { get; set; } public int Customers { get; set; } }`

Comment: It would be helpful to provide a minimal example of what your trying to achieve.At this point its unclear, and any answer will be based off multiple assumptions.

Answer (score 1):

This may be the ugliest thing I've ever written, and makes some assumptions on what you're doing, but I think this gets you what you want:

```
var query = from outerDictionary in x
            from listOfDictionaries in outerDictionary.Values
            from innerDictionary in listOfDictionaries
            from keyValuePairs in innerDictionary
            group keyValuePairs by keyValuePairs.Key into finalGroup
            select new
            {
                Key = finalGroup.Key,
                Sum = finalGroup.Sum(a => Convert.ToInt32(a.Value))
            };
```

Where x is your main List.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so it looks like that you were attempting to create an Dictionary of Items with various properties (Cost, Customers, etc...), which begs the question: why not just create a class?

After all, it would be pretty simple to turn your dictionary of dictionary of items into a single dictionary of properties, such as below.

```
public class ItemProperties 
{
public double Price {get; set;} = 0;
public int Customers {get; set;} = 0;
//Whichever other properties you were thinking of using. 
}

static ItemProperties AddAll(Dictionary<string, ItemProperties> items)
ItemProperties finalitem = new ItemProperties(); 
{
foreach (var item in items) 
{
finalitem.Price += item.Price;
finalitem.Customers += item.Customers;
//Repeat for all other existing properties.
}
return finalitem;
}
```

Of course, this only works if the number and kind of properties is immutable. Another way to approach this problem would be to use TryParse to find properties in Dictionary2 that you think can be added. This is problematic however, and requires some good error checking.

```
static Dictionary < string, string > AddNestedDictionary(Dictionary < string, Dictionary < string, string > items) {

 Dictionary < string, string > finalitem = new Dictionary < string, string > ();
 foreach(var item in items) {
  foreach(var prop in item) {
   if (!finalitem.ContainsKey(prop.Key)) {
    finalitem.Add(prop);
   }
   double i = 0;
   if (Double.TryParse(prop.Value, out i)) {
    finalitem[prop.Key] += i;
   }
  }
 }
return finalitem;
}
```

Again, not the best answer compared to the simplicity of a static class. But that would be the price you pay for nonclarity.